# Convert Array to json with json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have an array with the output (print_r):

```
Array
(
[a] => 706
[b] => 194
[c] => 164
[d] => 44
[e] => 42
[f] => 41
[g] => 40
[h] => 38
[i] => 13
)
```

I need to convert it to a json of this format:

```
[{"name":"a","value":706},{"name":"b","value":194},{"name":"c","value":164},{"name":"d","value":44},{"name":"e","value":42},{"name":"f","value":41},{"name":"g","value":40},{"name":"h","value":38},{"name":"i","value":13}]
```

This is what I've tried but I'm just guessing and not getting the right output :

```
 echo  '[';
foreach($sortedArray as $key => $value) {
echo  $dataTable = json_encode(array(
    'name' => $key,
    'value' => $value
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
};
 echo  ']';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keyPair = array();
foreach($sortedArray as $key => $value) {
  $keyPair[] = array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value);
}
echo json_encode($keyPair);
```

http://codepad.org/xApWlo7j

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array(
  'a' => 234, 'b' => 2343, 'c' => 23423, /* etc. */
);

$new_data = array();
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
  $new_data[] = array(
    'name' => $k, 'value' => (number)$v
  );
}

print json_encode($new_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```php
$arr = array(
  'a' => 706,
  'b' => 194,
  'c' => 164,
  'd' => 44,
  'e' => 42,
  'f' => 41,
  'g' => 40,
  'h' => 38,
  'i' => 13);

$map_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
  $map_arr[] = array('name' => $k, 'value' => intval($v));

print json_encode($map_arr);
```

**Result**

```
[{"name":"a","value":706},{"name":"b","value":194},{"name":"c","value":164},      
{"name":"d","value":44},{"name":"e","value":42},{"name":"f","value":41},
{"name":"g","value":40},{"name":"h","value":38},{"name":"i","value":13}]
```

I tried to link my example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, but the share CAPTCHA is disabled...